# Show that $|\frac {\sin x}{x}| < 1$ for all $ x \in \Bbb R $\ $\{0\}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Problem : Show that $\left|\frac {\sin x}{x}\right| < 1$ for all $ x \in \Bbb R $\ $\{0\}$.

The result seems obvious for $|x| \geq 1$, but I am not sure how to show it on the interval $(-1,0) \cup (0, 1)$. it seems this amounts to showing that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {|x^{2n}|}{(2n+1)!} < 1$, but I am not sure how to proceed, hints appreciated.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\sin\left(x\right) \over x} = \cos\left(\xi\right)\,,\quad 0 < \left\vert\xi\right\vert < \left\vert x\right\vert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0 \le x <1$, let

$f (x)=\sin (x)-x .$

$0 <x <1 \implies $

$f'(x)=\cos (x)-1 <0$

$\implies f $ strictly decreasing at $(0,1) $

$\implies \sin (x)-x < f (0)=0$

$\implies 0 \le \frac {\sin (x)}{x} <1$

observe that $f $ is odd.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

For the case $x\in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$, consider a sector of a unit circle, with $x$ being the angle at the centre. The area is $$\frac12 |x|$$

Remove the circular segment from the sector, and what remains is a triangle. The area is

$$\frac12 |\sin x|$$

Since the triangle is just a part of the sector,
$$|\sin x| < |x|$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the fact that $y=x$ is the line tangent to $y=\sin x$ at $x=0$ and $\sin x$ is concave down for $0< x< \pi$

Answer (score 1):

For some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$, the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}=\cos(\xi)\tag{1}
$$
Since $|\cos(\xi)|\lt1$ for all $\xi\ne0$ and $|\xi|\lt1$, $(1)$ implies that for $|x|\le1$
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\lt1\tag{2}
$$
Since $|\sin(x)|\le1$ for all $x$, we have $(2)$ for $|x|\gt1$, too. Thus, $(2)$ is true for all $x\ne0$.

Comment: Nice ! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Since it's even, you only need to consider $x>0$.

Because
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x = \cos x$$
so
$$1 > \frac{d}{dx}\sin x > -1$$
for $1>x>0$

Therefore
$$x > \sin x > -x$$
for $1>x>0$